# Confluent Schema Registry 7.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-schema-registry

I am working with confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.1.
What can I say, its a little temperamental. Will crash every time with a message

***ERROR The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. You must configure the topic to 'compact' cleanup***

Within my Spring Boot app, I have configured the TopicBuilder to suggest

```
.config(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, "compact")
```

But problem is while running gradle composeUp, the container simply crashes without a possibility of salvation. I am not running an external Kafka instance to be able to configure with `kafka-topics` command, or `cleanup.policy` option. Not that I haven't tried providing some of these options in the `docker-compose.yml` but they all are ignored. Short of running Kafka and registry in my local env and the pipeline, is there any other alternative to this Confluent container at all?

Comment: Hard to understand what you're doing. Spring doesn't control the Registry settings, only the Docker Compose environment variables do. What do you mean "ignored"? And the Registry requires a Kafka broker, so what do you mean that you're not running it?

Comment: Not sure what else to convey @OneCricketeer. As I said, my container crashes, I want it up and running, the topic(s) are created automatically, my app will eventually use it to send messages around

Comment: I have tried adding properties like `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_TOPIC_CLEANUP_POLICY=compact` and `LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: compact` and doesn't seem to make a difference. Question is, if there are such properties that can be used in non-CLI environments

Comment: According to the Schema Registry config documentation `topic.cleanup.policy` doesn't exist, so I'm not sure why you'd expect that to work. You should edit your question to show the compose file... All properties that are documented work for all environments, and aren't really relevant to Spring, was my initial point. And you still didn't clarify "am not running an external Kafka instance"